# MYSQL Rollback with a set of LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, rollback, load-data-infile

I use a batch file to load my tables from CSV files using numerous LOAD DATA INFILE commands. When an error occurs during one of a table's LOAD statements, rollback occurs only for that table with 0 rows, while the data in other tables remains committed. Please advise on how to make this transaction-bound. I discovered a similar article here [MySQL: Executing LOAD statements inside Transaction from a sql script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088509/mysql-executing-load-statements-inside-transaction-from-a-sql-script-file#_=_), however there is no answer.

Comment: "Batch file" meaning what, specifically, here?

Comment: a set of load data infile, like this: SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file1.csv' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file2.csv' INTO TABLE table2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
.
.
.
LOAD DATA INFILE 'fileN.csv' INTO TABLE tableN FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
COMMIT;

Comment: If one load failed, 0 rows inserted, but the rest of the tables still loaded. what I want to do is, if any of the load failed, nothing will load, tables and data remain the same as the last load.

Comment: Unlike other databases, MySQL does not have transaction support for schema changes, so there's no way to lock this all inside a transaction. You may need to unwind manually.

Comment: @tadman LOAD DATA is not a schema change.

Comment: What storage engine are you using? The documentation mentions that `LOAD DATA` causes an implicit commit with NDB.

Comment: I don't know what storage engine I am using. How to find out?

Comment: Please add details of your "batch file", and how you are executing it, to your question. If using `mysql < your_batch_file` then execution will stop on error, causing a rollback. You can run `show engines;` to see which ones are available, or `select table_name, engine from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_db_name' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';` to list the engine for each table in your db.